# Can't install package via opam

Tags: software-installation, package-management

I use Ubuntu 16.10 and I'm trying to install `conf-gtksourceview` via opam but the following error occurs:

```
This package requires gtksourceview 2.0 development packages installed on your system
```

How do I install it? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [`libgtksourceview2.0-dev`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtksourceview2); for example, using `apt`:

```
sudo apt install libgtksourceview2.0-dev
```

Comment: Thank you,  I was trying to install gtksourceview2.0-dev so I couldn't find it

Comment: In these situations `apt-cache search` comes in handy — `apt-cache search gtksourceview` finds the appropriate package.